# PDF Writing Text become lighter ItextSharp

Tags: .net, vb.net, pdf, itext

I am Writing some text to create pdf using itextsharp. first i create a pdfdocument then i add page and then i write text font look shiny and bold same text write again at x,y place in pdf it become lighter and so on. it is so strange. but it is happending. please support[image]

```
`Dim PdfDoc As New Document(New iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(640.08F, 881.28F))    
Dim pdfWrtr As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(PdfDoc, New FileStream(_FolderPath & "\" & "TST" & ".pdf", FileMode.Create)   
PdfDoc.Open()                                                              
PdfDoc.NewPage()  
Dim cb As PdfContentByte = pdfWrtr.DirectContent   
Dim bf As BaseFont = Nothing
bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(Application.StartupPath & "\OcrB.ttf", BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED)       
cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 16)             
cb.BeginText()         
cb.ShowTextAligned(0, ("MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"), 85, 850,0)  
cb.EndText()


bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(Application.StartupPath & "\OcrB.ttf", BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED)    
cb.SetFontAndSize(bf, 16)    
cb.BeginText()     
cb.ShowTextAligned(0, ("MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"), 85, 800,0)                      
cb.EndText()         
PdfDoc.Close()
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you have two different declarations of `cb`, one is pdfDoc.DirectContent and the other is psDoc.DirectContent. I can't find psDoc in the code either.

Comment: Edited Done. it was Posting Issue

Comment: Your sample code still doesn't work. `DirectContent` is not a method of a `Document`, it's a method of `PdfWriter`. `SetFontAndSize`, `BeginText`, and `ShowTextAligned` are methods for PdfContentByte, they aren't stand alone methods. Please post sample code that reproduces the issue and I will try and help. But if your sample code is already broken, there's not much I can do.

Comment: now check exactly you r saying write there was issue in code. now it is fixed thanks for your observation

Comment: Where the text was written twice in the same spot, it looked darker when I was zoomed out in the PDF file. However, zooming into the writing shows the font and letters are identical, there is no difference in the pixels. What you are seeing is probably your PDF reader making the text appear bold indicating there is text stacked on top of text. If you zoom in at 3000%, you will see all the text is the same color and the same size.

Comment: yup..! your saying right but em not writing text twicely at the same place. if you see the image i have posted first line color is darker and second line color is lighter. i did print but result is same as it showing in soft file.

Comment: The image you posted is not the same as the output of your sample code. The sample code you posted is writing the same text in the same location twice.

Comment: @MuhammadWaseem As an aside... the iText API you use in your code is very low level. This in particular means that your calls essentially correspond 1:1 with the PDF content stream instructions. If you recognize something funny like you seemingly did, chances are you have found a quirk of your viewer or a bug in your own code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide a PDF and you didn't even share an exact copy of your code, which makes it almost impossible to give you an accurate answer, but based on experience, I would say that you have a problem that is related to color blending.

Try adding

```
pdfWrtr.RgbTransparencyBlending = true;
```

The default blending colorspace in PDF is CMYK and will result in faded colors in the screen and in printing. Changing the color blending to RGB colors will avoid this effect.